# На моём вопросе висят тревоги за опечатки, хотя опечаток нет. Что с этим можно сделать?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, причины-закрытия

Я недавно задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285913/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jpql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-manytomany). Толком ответа не получил *(ну кроме комментария одного)*, подзабил и пошёл искать решение дальше. Захожу сегодня - а мне там уже флажков накидали. Причём все тревоги по причине **"Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводиться, или опечаткой"**.

Проблема **НЕ В ОПЕЧАТКЕ**, причём это может увидеть кто угодно, кто немного знает Spring и хотя бы немного вчитается в вопрос. Проблема **ОТЛИЧНО ВОСПРОИЗВОДИТСЯ**, хотя, конечно, вряд ли кто-то из поставивших тревогу хотя бы вчитывался в приведённый мной код. Проблема в синтаксисе, но проблемы с синтаксисом - это не опечатка, это именно мой пробел в знаниях, который я пытаюсь закрыть.

Вопрос на самом деле имеет под собой реальную проблему, с которой я не первый раз сталкиваюсь. Такое ощущение, что флажки накидали чисто из-за стадного инстинкта. Конечно, может я ошибаюсь, но мне в коментах никто из трёх людей не отписался, а в голову я им залезть не могу.

Вопрос вот в чём - что мне делать? Как-то можно обнулить эти тревоги? А то ещё два человека поддадутся влиянию своих предшественников *(вроде бы тревоги можно видеть, поправьте, если я ошибаюсь)* и закроют мой вопрос. А я этого не хочу.

**P.S.: Допускаю, что вопрос может быть плохо сформулирован или непонятен, но тогда тревоги надо подходящие ставить, а не опечатку.**

**P.P.S.: Допускаю, что проверяющие просто невнимательно смотрели. Но, чёрт возьми, я тоже проверяющий! Мне доступна очередь проверок для первых сообщений и у меня есть возможность ставить флажки! Но! Если я не понимаю вопрос и мне лень вникать, то я его пропускаю, а не ставлю тревогу!**

Comment: Всегда можно отредактировать вопрос, добавив информацию и описание почему ты считаешь, что проблема не в опечатке.

Comment: @Grundy а зачем его редактировать? Он вроде бы и так неплох. Опечаток по-крайней мере я не вижу. Ну и плюс тревоги-то останутся, я так понимаю, и вопрос будет в зоне риска

Comment: _а зачем его редактировать? Он вроде бы и так неплох._ - только на твой взгляд, но как ты уже убедился, другие пользователи могут иметь иное мнение, поэтому стоит добавлять всю необходимую информацию непосредственно в вопрос. _вопрос будет в зоне риска_ - любой вопрос находится в "зоне риска" так как его могут закрыть.

Comment: @Grundy просто не знаю, что ещё добавлять) Минимальный исполняемый код в спринге - довольно объёмная штука, которую мало кто читать захочет, поэтому я постарался ограничиться адекватным минимумом) Но я попробую как-нибудь улучшить вопрос.

Comment: Вот посмотрите: _да, работает. Вот такой запрос сделал <запрос>. Дубликаты только возвращает блин. Ну уж попробую разобраться:)_, как нужно понимать эту фразу? Причина закрытия не связана с опечаткой, а именно с этой фразой. Под причину _Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой_, часто попадают вопросы, где автор в комментарии или самоответе озвучил, что проблема решена и в её решении он болше не нуждается. Я так это понял и проголосовал за закрытие (голос это не тревога!). В награду за проделанную работу поставил вопросу плюс, один из них там мой.

Comment: @0xdb ну я обычно отвечаю на свои вопросы, если нахожу ответ. А если вопрос глупый (из-за опечатки например проблема была) - то удаляю. Ну и я всё-таки написал там, что возвращаются дубликаты, то есть проблема не совсем решена. Понимаю конечно, что я - это я, а людей разных много... Не думал, что обращают внимание на комментарий.

Comment: а) _обычно отвечаю на свои вопросы_, тогда не пишите комментарий, а отвечайте.  б) _всё-таки написал там, что возвращаются дубликаты, то есть проблема не совсем решена_, нет, вы конкретно написали: _Ну уж попробую разобраться_, может вы другое имели ввиду, но все читают, а не пытаются ваши мысли угадать.

Comment: @0xdb ну формулировка неудачная, согласен. Но вопрос по факту не решён, ответ писать рано. Отредактировать комментарий я к сожалению уже не могу, удалять не хотелось бы, всё-таки он содержит в себе некоторую информацию. Потом найду ответ и напишу его как ответ.

Comment: _удалять не хотелось бы, всё-таки он содержит в себе некоторую информацию_,  вся некоторая информация должна хранится где-угодно, но только не в комментарии. Комментарии служат для утоточнений, и после того, как всё выяснено - их надо перенести в вопрос/ответ, или просто удалить.  Я отозвал голос, но пока комментарий под вопросом виден, кто-то ещё может проголосовать за закрытие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы видите, что вопрос пытаются закрыть с ошибочной причиной, я бы предложил в первую очередь написать соответствующий комментарий под вопросом (или может быть даже отредактировать вопрос, если ошибочность причины не достаточно очевидна).

Иногда закрытие действительно случается под влиянием стадного инстинкта, но это достаточно редкие случаи, которые в дальнейшем приводят к последующему скорому переоткрытию.

Дополнительно хочу заметить, что в очереди на закрытие уже есть голос "Оставить открытым" для вашего вопроса:

> [image: Оставить открытым]

Это значит, что из очереди на закрытие вопрос может в скором времени пропасть, а имеющиеся голоса на закрытие со временем сгорят.

И, кстати, это не тревоги, а голоса на закрытие. Одноимённую тревогу могут ставять участники, у которых ещё нет права голоса на закрытие. Но сами по себе тревоги не увеличивают количество голосов закрытия на вопросе, а всего лишь способствует появлению вопроса в очереди проверок.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. У меня нет доступа к очереди на закрытие, поэтому я не знал, что можно голосовать и ПРОТИВ закрытия. Тогда я напишу комментарий и попробую отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: @Zhenyria [краткая выжимка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0wax.png) по работе с очередью на закрытие. [Полная справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close) пока ещё не переведена на сайте.